# Calling as a list by filtering values in a Data Frame

Tags: list, dataframe, for-loop, numeric

I'm trying to write a code that returns only the numeric values greater than zero in a Data frame with column names as a list using for-loop,

but I couldn't succeed. How do you think I can fix this error and how can I solve this problem?

The code I wrote is below:

```
col=df.columns
for i in col:
    Liste=[]
    index=[]
    for j in range(40):
        if i[j] != 0:
            Liste=Liste + i[j]
            index=index + j
    i=zip(index,Liste)
```

I get this error;

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_98056/4001655036.py in <module>
      5     for j in range(40):
      6         if i[j] != 0:
----> 7             Liste=Liste + i[j]
      8             index=index + j
      9     i=zip(index,Liste)

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

[My Data Frame is like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7iW3.png)

Comment: "fix this error": which error? you don't show any errors!

Comment: I have added error that I got

Comment: the error tells you what's wrong!

Comment: I can see that but the written error shows the error is what stems from but it doesn't provide a   solution everytime

Comment: exactly, but the trick is (as the answer illustrates) really understanding what the error *means*. Then, you can start looking at the documetntation of your library (I guess that's pandas in this case) and see how to do it "right". Otherwise you'd need to ask for every single problem – which is very time-consuming.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of + operator with lists is to concatenate lists.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = list1 + list2.  # Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In your code the problem is at line where you are trying to append the item to list:

```
Liste=Liste + i[j]
```

I am fairly sure you intend to add item to the list, thus replace the line with this line:

```
Liste.append(i[j]). # no need for Liste on left hand side, since append with modify the list
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but not fixed. Probably there is another problem

Comment: atleast one more spot where you have similar problem is at
```index=index + j```
 change the line -  
```index=index + j ``` to  ```index.append(j)```